# ¿Cómo dar formato de fecha en Angular usando un pipe?

Tags: angular, angularjs, pipe, date-format

Necesito mostrar las fechas en el siguiente formato:

**viernes, 15 oct 2021**

actualmente estoy usando un pipe de esta manera:

```
<td class="center">{{consultar.fechaVencimiento | date:'fullDate':'+0'}}</td>
```

y  lo pinta asi en pantalla:

**viernes, 15 de octubre de 2021**

como puedo modificar el pipe para que el mes lo muestre como abreviado, y quite la palabra "de", asi como lo requiero

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste las opciones de formato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no requieres convertir la fecha entre diferentes zonas horarias puedes ocupar directamente un formato personalizado.

```js
<td class="center">{{consultar.fechaVencimiento | date:"EEEE, d MMM y"}}</td>
```

Comment: Puedes checar los diferentes tipos de formatos en la documentación oficial https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options